# good way to write thread safe middleware in django

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-middleware

I want apply required filtering for almost all models, all queries in quite big django application.
Actually I am looking for a right way to implement a "query-set driven" middleware (instead of standard "request-driven middleware")
but without manipulate any db driver (no patching, wrapping, etc).

Idea is to use one common mixin for QuerySets and Managers, to see this method always available:

`AnyModel.objects.filter_by_organization()`

without need to pass a parameter there.

and later:

`AnyModel.org_objects` doing `filter_by_organization()` own self

my main concern is about thread safety.
could you review my approach below?
this_thread = threading.local()

```
... standard django middleware:
class OrganizationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        this_thread.request = request

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if hasattr(this_thread, 'request'):
            del this_thread.request   # doubtful
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if hasattr(this_thread, 'request'):
            del this_thread.request   # doubtful
    ...

... mixin/manager:
class OrganizationQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
   def _get_current_request(self):
       return getattr(this_thread, "request", None)

   def filter_by_organization(self):
       request = self._get_current_request()
       org_id = getattr(request.user, 'organization_id', None)
       return self.filter(...filtering by org_id + extra logic...)
       # keeping this in one place has additional benefits

... in models: 
org_objects = OrganizationQuerySet.as_manager()

... then using above without a need to pass request
```

Comment: above seems to work, but lines `del this_thread.reques` are wrong because sum of executed `process_response` and `process_exception` in running Django is higher than sum of executed `process_request`.